# Rename a database in aws glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a database in aws glue that has '-' in its name.
This database contains a bunch of tables.
I would like to know whether this database can be renamed so that '-' can be replaced with '_'.
Did a lot of searching but could not find any solution.

Need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to rename an existing database in Glue.As per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html#schema-names)  You can use the AWS Glue Catalog Manager to rename columns, but at this time table names and database names cannot be changed using the AWS Glue console. To correct database names, you need to create a new database and copy tables to it (in other words, copy the metadata to a new entity). You can follow a similar process for tables. You can use the AWS Glue SDK or AWS CLI to do this.

[boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html) reference for Glue and [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/index.html) reference for Glue.

Comment: Can you explain the CLI command to copy tables to another database? Can we use the update-database CLI command in this case?